# NullPointerException в классе прохождения лабиринта

Tags: java

Пытаюсь написать прохождение лабиринта, но при запуске код прохождения падает в NullPointerException. Сам лабиринт в консоль выводится без проблем. Ошибка ссылается на этот участок кода:

```
public boolean nearExit() {
    Integer[] temp = new Integer[2];
    temp = path.peek();

    if (temp[1] == searchRoute[0].length - 2) {
        if (searchRoute[temp[0] + 1][temp[1]] == 'X') {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Весь код здесь:
https://github.com/kozloff13/MazeNavigator

Важно, чтобы при невозможности построения маршрута в консоль возвращалось null

Comment: А что отладка показывает?

Comment: @MBo Запускал в дебаггере, проходил все пошагово. Когда цикл проходит весь массив, появляется ошибка

Comment: А при этом path.peek успешно выполняется и temp заполнено чем-то правильным?

Comment: @MBo вижу при отладке, что temp заполнено нулем. Но при замене его на другое значение появляется та же ошибка в том же месте